# VHDL ATTRIBUTE keep

Tags: vhdl

I am currently studying VHDL about SR Latch, and there comes to a part which I don't understand.

Can anyone explain What does `ATTRIBUTE keep: boolean` mean and what does it do in VHDL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a user defined attribute, thus not part of the VHDL standard itself. It is typically used to instruct the synthesis tool that it should keep a certain signal, for example being a flip-flop, even through the synthesis tool may determine that the signal can be removed during optimization.

For Altera Quartus synthesis tool, see this description: [keep VHDL Synthesis Attribute](http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_keep.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Warning heavy Xilinx bias...

The attributes for the VHDL are different for different tools and even change between versions of the same tools. The "keep" attribute for Xilinx used to insure that in the Vivado synthesis process the signal is not optimized away. It has been renamed recently to "syn_keep" to avoid confusion. I've used similar attributes to fix build issues before in which the tools make false assumptions.

NOTE: In order to avoid optimization during the implementation for Xilinx use "dont_touch".

Example:
A clock coming into the FPGA needs to be buffer through the Xilinx BUFG, but I needed the raw signal for a specific IP core. So I split the route, buffer the clock and fed the raw clock signal to the IP. The Vivado 2016.4 tool optimized out the unbuffered route creating a time constraint critical warnings and misbehavior on the hardware. The issue was found by tracing through the synthesis design schematics, observing the proper routing, and then viewing the implementation design schematic and seeing the route is altered. I fixed this by adding the dont_touch attribute to the unbuffered signal.

```
attribute dont_touch              : boolean;
attribute clock_signal            : string;

attribute dont_touch of clk_in    : signal is true;
attribute clock_signal of clk_in  : signal is "yes"; 

...

CLK_BUFG: component BUFG
port map (
  I  => clk_in,
  O  => buf_clk_in
);
```

Comment: For the records, Vivado uses the `keep` attribute, the `syn_keep` attribute is specific to Synposis tools and will not work with Vivado synthesizer.